# Does proxy server also assign Internal IP to client?

Tags: nat, proxy-server

Proxy server injects X-Forwarded-For http header in client's request. If XFF is doing its job to forward every server's response to client then there is any need to assign internal IP and creating NAT table. Do they have to assign internal IP for working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP proxy works at the application layer. NAT works at the IP layer. These are two completely different things that do not know about each other and do not operate at the same level. Therefore your question doesn't make a ton of sense.

When an HTTP proxy receives a request for a webpage (and assuming the webpage is not already in the proxy's cache), it will open its own TCP connection to the destination HTTP server, issue its own HTTP request, parse the HTTP response, and then forwards the response to the client, which has its own TCP connection with the proxy. An HTTP proxy only understands the HTTP protocol and will not proxy any other protocol (note that for simplicity's sake I'm leaving aside more confusing stuff like `CONNECT` or multi-purpose proxies).

NAT is completely different. When forwarding an HTTP connection over a NAT there is only one direct TCP connection from the client to the server, NAT is only involved with keeping track of which internal endpoint (address and port) is talking to which external endpoint (address and port). NAT does not open TCP connections, it doesn't know what HTTP is, it doesn't parse requests or responses, and it certainly doesn't cache anything. NAT can forward any protocol (HTTP, ICMP, DNS…), as long as it's based on IP, since it doesn't need to know anything about the protocol in order to operate.

Note that I'm only describing simple configurations here. There are more complicated setups that might be confusing at first glance. One such configuration is a transparent proxy (also called intercepting proxy), which sits in the middle of the network path and actively intercepts HTTP connections that clients attempt to make to the outside. When such a connection is attempted, the transparent proxy rewrites the destination address such that the connection is redirected to the proxy instead. After that point everything behaves like I described above. This setup is used to force clients to go through the proxy without having to change their configuration. In that scenario the clients might not even be aware that their HTTP traffic is being proxied, as opposed to simply NAT'd. For more practical information about interception proxies, the [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) documentation has a [lot of information](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy) about this.

Comment: Can you explain about transparent proxies also because it is related? You didn't answer one thing, does proxy server assign you its own IP address to communicate with the user?

Comment: @user334283: I have updated my answer to provide more details regarding transparent proxies.

Comment: @user334283: "You didn't answer one thing, does proxy server assign you its own IP address to communicate with the user?" > I'm having trouble understanding your question. Again, the client opens its own TCP connection  the proxy, and then the proxy opens its own TCP connection to the server. Therefore there are 4 endpoints (address and port) at play here: one on the client, two on the proxy (one to communicate with the client, one to communicate with  the server), and one on the server.